# Twinfield API: how to get accesstoken using postman?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, oauth, twinfield

I'm trying to connect to the Twinfield API. I have registered an app in the developer portal, and created a callback URI. My call looks as follows:

```
https://login.twinfield.com/auth/authentication/connect/authorize?redirect_uri=https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback&response_type=id_token+token&client_id=###&client_secret=#####
```

[Link](https://accounting.twinfield.com/webservices/documentation/#/) to twinfield api documentation

However I get the error stating that the client application is not known or is not authorized.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and include a link to the documentation for authorization with this api.  **&response_type=id_token+token** doesn't normally take a client id and client secrete.

Comment: I edited the question, when I leave out the cient secret, it still does not work

Comment: are you sure you should be using the implicate flow with the client id you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you are missing the code, see below the `response_type`

```
&response_type=code&scope=openid+twf.user+twf.organisation+twf.organisationUser+offline_access&redirect_uri=https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback&
```

Once you've run this, you get a code and together with `basic64encoding` of your `client_id:client_secret` would profide you an access code.

The whole request should look like:

```
https://login.twinfield.com/auth/authentication/connect/authorize?client_id={xxxx}&response_type=code&scope=openid+twf.user+twf.organisation+twf.organisationUser+offline_access&redirect_uri=https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback&state=SOME_RANDOM_STATE&nonce=SOME_RANDOM_NONCE
```

for me to get this working in `postman` I need to copy the whole link into the browser, login there and then get from the return link the code when you see the page "Your call is authenticated"